# List of detected controller classes in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any way to get a list of detected controllers in MVC 6?
I don't want to use reflection.
The only place I found is on the ApplicationModel in the Apply method of IApplicationModelConvention, but it feels like there should be another and better way...

Comment: why don't you want to use reflection ?

Comment: Because I want to use same logic as Mvc, and why do something that's allready been done and likely being cached :) And of course I would like to understand Mvc 6 better...

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution in RC2, just get ApplicationPartManager from DependencyInjection and do this:

```
    ApplicationPartManager appManager = <FROM DI>;

    var controllerFeature = new ControllerFeature();
    appManager.PopulateFeature(controllerFeature);

    foreach(var controller in controllerFeature.Controllers)
    {
        ...
    }
```